# session.connection() is undefined for the type session in hibernate code

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session

I'm facing issue with session.connection() method is not accepted while hibernate upgrade done from hibernate 3.6 to hibernate 4.1.2..could you provide some solution for replace session.connection method?

AuditLogInterceptor.java :

```
public class AuditLogInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor{

    Session session;
    private Set inserts = new HashSet();
    private Set updates = new HashSet();
    private Set deletes = new HashSet();

    public void setSession(Session session) {   
        this.session=session;
    }

    public boolean onSave(Object entity,Serializable id,
        Object[] state,String[] propertyNames,Type[] types)
        throws CallbackException {

        System.out.println("onSave");

        if (entity instanceof IAuditLog){
            inserts.add(entity);
        }
        return false;

    }

    public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity,Serializable id,
        Object[] currentState,Object[] previousState,
        String[] propertyNames,Type[] types)
        throws CallbackException {

        System.out.println("onFlushDirty");

        if (entity instanceof IAuditLog){
            updates.add(entity);
        }
        return false;

    }

    public void onDelete(Object entity, Serializable id, 
        Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, 
        Type[] types) {

        System.out.println("onDelete");

        if (entity instanceof IAuditLog){
            deletes.add(entity);
        }
    }

    //called before commit into database
    public void preFlush(Iterator iterator) {
        System.out.println("preFlush");
    }   


    //called after committed into database
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public void postFlush(Iterator iterator) {
        System.out.println("postFlush");
        TbMasUsers tmu = null;
        try{

            for (Iterator it = inserts.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                IAuditLog entity = (IAuditLog) it.next();
                System.out.println("postFlush - insert");

                try {

                AuditLogUtil.LogIt("Saved",entity, session.connection());
                    // session.doWork(entity);
                } catch (HibernateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }   

            for (Iterator it = updates.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                IAuditLog entity = (IAuditLog) it.next();
                System.out.println("postFlush - update");
                try {
                    AuditLogUtil.LogIt("Updated",entity, session.connection());
                } catch (HibernateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }   

            for (Iterator it = deletes.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                IAuditLog entity = (IAuditLog) it.next();
                System.out.println("postFlush - delete");
                try {
                    AuditLogUtil.LogIt("Deleted",entity, session.connection());
                } catch (HibernateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }   

        } finally {
            inserts.clear();
            updates.clear();
            deletes.clear();
        }
    }   

}
```

## AuditLogUtil.java:

```
public class AuditLogUtil{


    public static void LogIt(String action,
        IAuditLog entity, Connection conn) throws Exception{
        SessionServiceImpl sessionServiceImpl=new SessionServiceImpl();
        TbMasUsers tbMasUsers=(TbMasUsers) sessionServiceImpl.getUserInSession();
        Integer loingEmpId=Integer.parseInt(tbMasUsers.getIntEmpId().getStrEmpId());

        //SessionImpl sessionImpl = (SessionImpl) session;
        // Connection conn1 = sessionImpl.connection();
         Session tempSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession(conn);


        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("null")
            AuditLog auditRecord = new AuditLog(action,entity.getLogDeatil()
                    , new Date(),entity.getId(), entity.getClass().toString(),loingEmpId);
            tempSession.save(auditRecord);
            tempSession.flush();

        } finally { 
            tempSession.close();    

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: As you already tried, judging by the commented code, you should use `session.doWork()` API. A quick and dirty hack is to cast the `session` to `SessionImpl` where `connection()` method is available, but deprecated.

Comment: its not working while i'm trying now if you know code session.doWork() let me know code...thanks,,

Comment: I've added it as answer, so it can be well formatted

Answer (score 0):

`session.connection()` is deprecated in Hibernate 4, you should use `session.doWork()` API for this. In your case, something like this

```
    s.doWork(new Work() {

        @Override
        public void execute(Connection c) throws SQLException {
            AuditLogUtil.LogIt("Deleted",entity, c);
        }
    });
```

If you need to return a value from inside the `execute()` method, use `s.doReturningWork()`

```
    Map<Integer, String> result = s.doReturningWork(new ReturningWork<Map<Integer, String>>() {

        @Override
        public Map<Integer, String> execute(Connection c) {
            Map<Integer, String> someMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

            return someMap;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the doWork in session.

```
getSession().doWork(new Work(){
    @Override public void execute(    Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    }
  }
);
```

or use `sessionFactory.withOptions()` to modify the session to contain the specific connection.